# Javascript/PHP: Check if the value of an input exists already in the database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have a table that contains names and ids in my database, and I have an html form with an input that adds a name in that table, I want to warn the user whenever they try to add a name that already exists by doing a split on the input value, if the array's length is <= 2 I want only the first element, and then I use the "includes" function to check if the list of the names in the database contains the string I'm getting from the input, here's my html code:

```
<label for="nomConcessionnaire">Nom du concessionnaire</label>
<input type="text" class="infoConcessions" name="nom_concessionnaire" id="nomConcessionnaire" value="<?php echo $row['nom_concessionnaire']; ?>" onblur="compareNom()"/>
```

And my script:

```
function compareNom () {
        var nomSaisi = document.getElementById("nomConcessionnaire").value;
        var nomSplit = nomSaisi.split(' ', 3);
        console.log (nomSplit);
        if (nomSplit.length <= 2) {
            var nomSimple = nomSplit[0];
            <?php
                if (!empty($concessionnaires_rows)) {
                    for($i = 0; $i < count($concessionnaires_rows); $i++) {
                     echo '
                            if ('.$concessionnaires_rows[$i]['nom_concessionnaire'].'.includes(nomSimple)) {
                                alert("Ce nom apparaît dans la liste des concessionnaires déjà existants, voulez-vous quand même l\'ajouter ?");
                            }

                     ';

                    }
                }
            ?>
        }
    }
```

I use a javascript function with php loop of my table rows inside.
I'm getting this error everytime:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after condition.

I can't understand why.

Comment: I think it's just a syntax problem. You are mixing PHP with JS. In what file is your `function compareNom () {`? Is it a `.php` file? Maybe send it all in here.

Comment: Inspect the generated JavaScript in your browser's View Source and you can probably see the problem more easily.

Comment: @DVN-Anakin my function is in .php file

Comment: @ADyson I checked and in fact the onblur=compareNom() was not in the right input... But I still have an error message saying that my function is not defined

Comment: Did you put the compareNom function before or after your HTML in the page?

Comment: @ADyson my function is after my HTML code, I did the same for some other functions and they're working just fine

Comment: Are they working just fine when called inline from a HTML element? I could be wrong but it always seemed you had to define the function earlier in the page.

Comment: I have found the problem, it's from my condition: 
if ('.$concessionnaires_rows[$i]['nom_concessionnaire'].'.includes(nomSimple))
The $concessionnaires_rows[$i]['nom_concessionnaire'] must be an array, here it's a simple string

Comment: So do you know how to solve it?

Comment: really confused with your code dude, you are mixing up php and javascript, there is no way you can do php thing if javascript condition no, javascript is client side language and php is server side.

Comment: @MohammedKuram the intention might be for PHP to generate some JS which can then be used later if that condition is true. We don't really know, and it isn't particularly relevant to the issue.

Comment: It could help if you provide the result html that your page produced, specifically the javascript it emitted with the alert.

Comment: The solution was to get the text contained in my select dropdown options transform it to an array and then do my split function, loop my array and display a message whenever my input exists in my array, and this is working. The reason why I used some PHP code is to get the list of names I needed from my database, but I have found this solution to get them from my select options.